# Fish codility excercise

Tags: php, algorithm, stack, time-complexity

Trying to solve this challenge on codility [fish challenge](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/fish/) I cannot understand why not all the tests are passed by my code.

```
function solution($A, $B) {
  // write your code in PHP7.0
  $stack =[];

  foreach($A as $key =>$value) {
    if(empty($stack)){
      array_push($stack,$key);
    }
    else if($B[count($stack)-1] == 1 && $B[$key]==0 )
    {
      if($value > $A[count($stack)-1])
      {
        array_pop($stack);
        array_push($stack,$key);
      }
    }
    else array_push($stack,$key);
  }
  return count($stack);
}
```

Comment: Why you don't push an element if the stack is empty?

Comment: I am pushing one element if stack is empty

Comment: Ok. This condition `else if($B[count($stack)-1] == 1 && $B[$key]==0 )`. You only remove one element from stack, write?

Comment: But you need to remove all items which are smaller then `$value` until it meets the item which goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. The code does not reference items on the stack correctly. Use  `$B[$stack[count($stack)-1]]` instead of `$B[count($stack)-1]`. Use  `$A[$stack[count($stack)-1]]` not `$A[count($stack)-1]`.
2. Fish going upstream must fight every fish coming downstream, not just the first one that they meet.

The following is a successful solution:

```
function solution($A, $B) {
  // write your code in PHP7.0
  $stack = [];
  $key = 0;
  while($key < count($A)) {
    if(empty($stack)){
      array_push($stack,$key);
      $key++;
    }
    else if($B[$stack[count($stack)-1]] == 1 && $B[$key] == 0){
      if($A[$key] > $A[$stack[count($stack)-1]])
      {
        // fish going upstream eats fish going downstream
        array_pop($stack);
      } else {
        // fish going downstream eats fish going upstream
        $key++;
      }
    }
    else {
      array_push($stack,$key);
      $key++;
    }
  }
  return count($stack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python solution with 100% score**

```
def solution(A, B):
    ds = []
    up = 0

    for i in range(len(A)):
        if B[i] == 1:
            ds.append(A[i])
        if B[i] == 0:
            if len(ds) == 0:
                up += 1
                continue
            while (len(ds) > 0):
                ele = ds.pop()
                if ele < A[i]:
                    continue
                else:
                    ds.append(ele)
                    break
            if len(ds) == 0:
                up += 1
    return len(ds) + up
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
  function solution($A, $B) {
  // write your code in PHP7.0
  $stack =[];

  foreach($A as $key =>$value) {
    if(empty($stack)){
      array_push($stack,$key);
    }
    else if($B[count($stack)-1] == 1 && $B[$key]==0 )
    {
        while(true) {
          if($value > $A[count($stack)-1] && !empty($stack) && $B[count($stack)-1] == 1)
          {
            array_pop($stack);
          }
          else break;
        }
      array_push($stack,$key);
    }
    else array_push($stack,$key);
  }
  return count($stack);

}
```